# Node.JS JSON.parse error undefined

Tags: json, node.js, parsing

I tried to parse json file in node
but there always error
and I google it but cannot solve it .
Can you help me?

```
undefined:1
undefined
^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token u
at Object.parse (native)
at Object.<anonymous> (app.js:13:19)
at Module._compile (module.js:449:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:467:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
at Module.runMain (module.js:492:10)
at process.startup.processNextTick.process._tickCallback (node.js:244:9)
```

this's my code

```
var app = express();
var mongodb = require("mongoskin");
var fs = require('fs');

var content;
fs.readFile('./config/db.json', function read(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    }
    content = data;
});
var config = JSON.parse(content);


app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.send(config.left);
});

app.listen(process.env.VCAP_APP_PORT || 3000);
```

and the db.json is this. As you can see, there are no errors.

```
{
  "left": 3
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`readFile` is *asynchronous*, so your `JSON.parse` line is called before you assign a value to `content`, and so `content` has its default value of `undefined`.

You have two options:

1. Move the logic using the data *into* the callback.

   ```
   var app = express();
   var mongodb = require("mongoskin");
   var fs = require('fs');

   fs.readFile('./config/db.json', function read(err, data) {
       if (err) {
           throw err;
       }

       var config = JSON.parse(data); // <=== Note I'm using `data`, not `content`; we don't need a `content` variable anymore

       app.get('/', function(req, res){
           res.send(config.left);
       });

       app.listen(process.env.VCAP_APP_PORT || 3000);
   });
   ```
2. Use the synchronous version of `readFile` (which is `readFileSync`).

   ```
   // ...
   content = fs.readFileSync('./config/db.json');

   var config = JSON.parse(content);
   // ...
   ```

Answer (score 0):

`content` is equal to `undefined` when you try to parse it.
You should parse your JSON data in the `readFile` callback or use `readFileSync` instead.

Also you should probably not throw from a callback.

This leads me to think that you have some misconceptions of how node.js works and I strongly recommend you read [this](http://www.nodebeginner.org/)